# Purpose of the diode in this comparator circuit

Tags: comparator

Follow up to the question here: [Generated sound](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622696/generated-sound)

I now understand better the oscillator circuit, but what's the purpose of the diode here?

I want to learn more on the topic, but I don't know where to start and if there is a name associated with this forward feedback?
Is it there to bias positively the resulting wave-form, and why would you do that in an audio circuit?

[image]

Comment: One more question.
My ultimate goal is to contribute to MAME by supporting this circuitry. Feel free to PM me.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624087/lm139-equivalent-circuit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

The 339 would not oscillate without the diode. It toggles the reference voltage at IN+ to produce new target voltages for IN-. The circuit has properties of a VCO.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jens said in his answer, the circuit has the properties of a VCO, but it is a "weird" VCO. EE&O. Somebody to confirm?

For those interested, here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/usd5c7e3sv9yaz9/op%20amp%20sound%20gen%20v030.cir?dl=0) of the file. Just zoom also the "double pulse".

[image]
Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip), just click (in the simulator) on the switches to change the configuration.

Here is what I get when simulating this circuit (driven by a Voltage supply, test).

[image]

And a "zoom" in the picture ... for some voltage, it is a "double" pulse.

[image]